# Evaluating the integral $ \int \bigl(\bigl(1-\frac{1}{2}z^2\bigr)^{-2}-1\bigr)^{-1/2} dz$ involved in the Young–Laplace equation

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Through working on the Young-Laplace equation I cam across the following integral and Maple is acting strange:

> $$ \int{\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{\left(1-\frac{z^2}{2}\right)^2}-1}} \, dz} .$$

If anyone could point me to a resource which discusses integrals of this type that would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Can you be more specific about "acting strange" ?

Comment: If I add a undefined constant such that the denominator looks like

$1-\frac{k^2z^2}{2}$ it produces a solution interns of logs and if I set k = 1 then I get a solution in terms of an arctan() function which doesn't make sense.

Comment: Because of the form $1 - u^2$, one should expect a solution in terms of the *hyperbolic* arctangent function, no?

Comment: The books on fluid mechanics by Batchelor and Landau & Lifshitz both give the solution in terms of $\arcosh()$ which I can achieve through the log function but not through the $\arctan()$ function.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Rearranging gives that the integrand is

$$\left\vert\frac{z^2 - 2}{z}\right\vert \frac{1}{\sqrt{4 - z^2}} .$$

At least on any interval where the sign of $\frac{z^2 - 2}{z}$ does not change, this can be handled by, e.g., hyperbolic trigonometric substitution.